# Solve Undetermined Coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$y'' + 10y' + 25y = 512e^{3t}$

$y(0) = 5$

$y'(0) = 7$

I solved for the homogenous portion and got:

$y(x) = c_1e^{-5x} + c_2e^{-5x}$

Then I solved for particular solutions, well tried:

$Yp = Ae^{3t}$

$Yp' = 3Ae^{3t}$

$Yp'' = 9ce^{3t}$

$Yp = 8e^{3t}$

Apply initial conditions to find $c_1$ and $c_2$.

Comment: Your homogeneous  solution is incorrect.  One of the exponential functions should be multiplied by $t$.

Comment: The second one? Because I thought so, but his example didn't show it, but I may have just forgotten to write it down.

Comment: Why not read the material on "undetermined coefficients" in a DE textbook?  That will be more efficient than asking multiple questions here.

Comment: This class is not provided with a text to buy, it is taught by online lectures notes that are not very effective.

Comment: You're mixing up your $x$'s and $t$'s.  There's no need for the extra factor of $x$ in the definition of $y_p$, since the forcing function (the guy on the right) is not a multiple of any homogeneous solution.  It suffices to let $y_p  = ce^{3t}$.  It's moot, but you didn't get the derivative of $y_p$ right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:  Since $e^{3t}$ is not a solution to the homogeneous equation you should guess that the particular solution is $y_p(t) = Ae^{3t}$.  Substitute this into your ODE and yield one equation with one unknown.

Comment: I found that the Yp = 8e^(3t). Where do I go from there?

Comment: The solution is the sum of the particular and homogeneous solutions.

Comment: Ok, thank you! To find c_1 and c_2, would you just apply the initial conditions to y and y' ?

Comment: yes, that is correct.